# Problems while compiling Spark with maven

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to compile Spark 1.2.0 using maven 3.2.2, scala 2.10.4, java 1.8.0_05 and what I'm getting is:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS [  3.513 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SUCCESS [  8.909 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ............ SUCCESS [  6.625 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. FAILURE [01:06 min]
[INFO] Spark Project Bagel ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Twitter ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume Sink .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Flume ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External MQTT ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External ZeroMQ ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project External Kafka ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:26 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-17T22:10:43+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/554M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: Compilation failed
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:105)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
    at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
    at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
    at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
    at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:184)
    at com.typesafe.zinc.Compiler.compile(Compiler.scala:164)
    at sbt_inc.SbtIncrementalCompiler.compile(SbtIncrementalCompiler.java:92)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.incrementalCompile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:303)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.compile(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:119)
    at scala_maven.ScalaCompilerSupport.doExecute(ScalaCompilerSupport.java:99)
    at scala_maven.ScalaMojoSupport.execute(ScalaMojoSupport.java:482)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    ... 20 more
```

Could you please guide me where might be the problem? I tried to find solution elsewhere. There was a problem reported in [SPARK-3794](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3794) but I think that I have patched version (although version description in jira ticket is weired).

I'm running packaging with following mvn command:

```
mvn -Dhadoop.version=2.4.1 -DskipTests clean package -X
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling it with `sbt` ? Note `sbt` is packaged with Spark sources and therefore you don't need to install it.

Comment: I've tried using sbt and also didn't succeed. But this is not the point - mvn is the recommended way so I would really appreciate a solution for the above problem with maven packaging.

Comment: Did u find a solution for this?

Comment: I have nearly the same issue with Spark 1.5.0 :(

Comment: I believe you snipped the relevant part of the error.  Run it again and check above the first line you posted for [error].

Comment: Same issue for Spark 1.5.1, I've tried `./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11` and then with `-Dscala-2.11`. It seems that lots of people are having the same issue, any new findings ? thanks

Answer (score 13):

**Concise**

The issue could be caused by or a combination of the following:

1. openjdk instead of oracle jdk
2. a zinc server is still running
3. The `JAVA_HOME` is incorrect

**Verbose**

The issue could be caused because **openjdk** was used:

```
user@host $ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b15)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b15, mixed mode)
```

instead of the **oracle** one. Once the path was updated, i.e.:

```
user@host $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

the issue did not occur anymore when the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/spark.git && \
cd spark && \
build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

were run and the build succeeded:

```
[INFO] Kafka 0.10 Source for Structured Streaming ......... SUCCESS [  9.715 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Java 8 Tests ......................... SUCCESS [  5.586 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 06:12 min (Wall Clock)
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-12-19T14:20:39+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/859M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

The issue could also caused because a Zinc server was still running, e.g.:

```
user@host $ ps -ef | grep -i zinc
```

once this process was killed using `kill <enter pid zinc server process>` the issue was solved.

---

Ensure that the `JAVA_HOME` is correct by issuing `JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_92` and verify it by issuing: `echo $JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score 5):

This might work for you.

Before build run:

```
./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.11
```

to change the Scala version.

Comment: I have a similar problem when compiling spark-2.0.0 and changing scala version does not resolve it.

Comment: This issue is still haunting spark 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

To compile Spark with maven, you should do the following steps

1. Change scala version to the scala version in your machine: `./dev/change-scala-version.sh <version>`
2. Shutdown zinc: `./build/zinc-<version>/bin/zinc -shutdown`
3. Compile Spark: `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-<version> -Dscala-<version> -DskipTests clean package`

Answer (score -2):

You might try disabling the use of Zinc Server from ./spark/pom.xml

Comment out

```
<!--<useZincServer>true</useZincServer>-->
```

I did this, then saw JVM Out of Memory Exception. That also might be the issue for you.